# Filter array by keyword is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I created an angular "filter component" to filter an array and print out its contents. I'm getting the keyword as `value` for filter array from another component by a service. In the html, `value` and the whole array is showing, but the filter array is not showing.

Below is my code:

**result.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { SendDataService } from "./../send-data.service";
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { JsoncallItem } from "./../jsoncall-item";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-result',
  templateUrl: './search-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-result.component.css']
})
export class SearchResultComponent implements OnInit {

    _postsArray: JsoncallItem[] = [];

    private postsURL ="http://myapp/browse/all/all";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private data: SendDataService){}

  getPosts(): void{
  this.http.get<JsoncallItem[]>(this.postsURL).
  subscribe(
      resultArray => {this._postsArray = resultArray['data'];
   })
  }

  value: string;

  filterarray: any[];

  showData(){
    this.filterarray=this._postsArray.filter(
        f => f.title.toLowerCase().includes(
          this.value.toLowerCase()))
    .map(searchname=>searchname.title)
  }

    ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getPosts();
    this.showData();
    this.data.currentValue.subscribe(value => this.value = value)

  }

}
```

**result.component.html**

```
<p>{{value}}</p>
<table">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of filterarray">
        <td>{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Only `{{value}}` is showing and `{{item}}` is not. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this.getPosts and this.showData both one after another on ngOnInit()

this.getPosts is an asynchronous call, hence your this.showData is being run before the results from this.getPosts is fetched. Hence there is nothing to filter :)

The solution to this is to put this.showData within the success callback of this.getPosts. Hence showData will only be called when the get method has completed successfully and there is some data to filter :)

Something like this.

```
getPosts(): void{
  this.http.get<JsoncallItem[]>(this.postsURL).
  subscribe(
      resultArray => {this._postsArray = resultArray['data'];
      this.showData();
   })
  }
```

And remove this.showData from ngOnInit()

Hope this helps.

Comment: now it shows the result, but without filtering, it shows the entire array!

Comment: check in this.showData if this.value has a value. maybe it's empty and that's why it shows all results because you do also initi it with a subscription and it may not be filled at that time.

Comment: try to execute " this.data.currentValue.subscribe(value => this.value = value)" this line on contructor().